# Why is the legend symbol alignment in Print Composer worse than in the main window layer list?

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer

I created a point layer where point-symbols' size depends on a column of the attribute table. When they appear in Layers Panel, symbols look like this (every circle's centroid has the same "X-value" on an imaginary axis):

[image]

But when it appears in Print Composer as a Legend, it looks like this:

[image]

So nice arrangement disappears and all become a bit wobbly.
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try tweaking the **Legend > Symbol > Symbol Width** setting as follows...

[image]

nudge the values up and down, you should see your symbols move from left-align to centre-align... (QGIS 2.16)

Comment: Thank you! Never thought that it would be as simple as that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another answer because I had the same issue, but the above solution did not entirely fix the problem.

For me, the issue was that QGIS had automatically added an x offset to my bubbles in the main map, to avoid overplotting. First, make sure your map is locked in the print composer (so that you don't create overplotting issues in the image). Then go to the layers panel in the main map, right-click on each bubble/symbol and choose edit symbol > simple marker > and adjust "offset X,Y" to zero.

After this go back to the print composer and update your legend only.

[image: Removing x offset for plotted points]